# Understanding the strong Markov property for stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-probability, markov-process

I'm studying a Markov process $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F}, \mu_0)$ with transition probabilities $\pi_n$ and with a stopping time $\tau:\mathcal{X}^\infty \to \mathbb{N}\cup\{0, \infty\}$.
Thus we have a space of all chains and a probability on it - $(\mathcal{X}^\infty, \mathcal{F}^\infty, P)$.
We also have a subalgebra $\mathcal{F}_\tau \subset \mathcal{F}^\infty$.
See page 16 of Varadhan's [notes](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/course/PROB.ch4.pdf) for the details.

Lemma 4.10 has an equation
\begin{equation}\label{Lemma}\tag{1}
P_x\left\lbrace X_{\tau+1} \in A_1, \dots , X_{\tau+n} \in A_n | \mathcal{F}_\tau \right\rbrace
= \int_{A_1}\dots \int_{A_n} \pi(x_{n-1},dx_n)\dots\pi(X_\tau, dx_1)
\end{equation}
which is claimed to hold 'a.e. on $\{\tau< \infty\}$.'

**Question 1:** What is the symbol $P_x$? The a.e. property on $\mathcal{X}^\infty$, and the fact that the Lemma states '$x=X_\tau$', leads me to believe I should read \eqref{Lemma} with a dependence on $\omega \in \mathcal{X}^\infty$ as follows:
\begin{equation}\label{omega}\tag{2}
P_{X_\tau(\omega)} \left\lbrace X_{\tau+1} \in A_1, \dots , X_{\tau+n} \in A_n | \mathcal{F}_\tau \right\rbrace
=\int_{A_1}\dots \int_{A_n} \pi(x_{n-1},dx_n)\dots\pi(X_\tau(\omega), dx_1)
\end{equation}
Further, the subscript notation leads me to believe we are disintegrating the measure $P$ on the subalgebra $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ as in Theorem 4.7 of the [notes](https://www.math.nyu.edu/%7Evaradhan/course/PROB.ch4.pdf).
On the other hand $X_\tau(\omega)$ is in $\mathcal{X}$ rather than $\mathcal{X}^\infty$...

So I ask again; what is $P_x$? Hope someone can clarify/dumb it down for me.

Comment: $P_x$ is the distribution of the Markov chain when $X_0=x$, i.e. when the chain starts at the value $x$.

Comment: Hi, How is it related to the probability $P$ on $\mathcal{X}^\infty$? Is there some disintegration going on?

Comment: It is unclear to me what $P$ is here (except a probability measure on $\mathcal{X}^\infty$). For any probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{X}$ you will have a probability measure $P_\mu$ on $\mathcal{X}^\infty$ which is the law of the Markov chain $X$ where the initial distribution (the distribution of $X_0$) is $\mu$. When $\mu$ is concentrated at one point $x\in\mathcal{X}$, i.e. when $\mu=\delta_x$, one typically writes $P_x$ instead of $P_{\delta_x}$.

Comment: Ohk, so we're supposed to change to $\delta_x$ as the initial probability and keep the same transitions $\pi_0, \pi_1,\dots$ to induce $P_x$ on the entire space $\mathcal{X}^\infty$? But then why the conditional symbol on $\mathcal{F}_\tau$? And where is the $x$ on the right hand side of equation $(1)$? And what about the 'a.e. on ${\tau<\infty}$' thing? Is it a.e. $P$ or a.e. $P_x$? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Exactly. When we write $P_x$ we "set" the initial distribution to $\delta_x$ but we do not change the transitions. When we condition on $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ we condition on the random variables $X_0,X_1,\dotsc,X_\tau$. What (1) tells you is that although you condition on the entire path up to time $\tau$, the future (i.e. the part of the path from time $\tau+1$ and onwards) depends only on the value of $X_\tau$. This is the strong Markov property. Finally, it should be $P_x$-a.e. on $\{\tau<\infty\}$.

Comment: $X_\tau(\omega):= X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$ so I'm not sure what you mean by $X_0, X_1, \dots, X_\tau$. This is a sequence of random variables that changes according to $\omega$? Can you please explain the 'condition on ...' further? Which probability, which subalgebra? Also, where is the $x$ on the right hand side? We are supposed to fix $x$ from the outset, right?

Comment: For a fixed $x$ you have the probability measure $P_x$ on $\mathcal{X}^\infty$. Here you also have a sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. So $P_x(X_{\tau+1}\in A_1,\dotsc,X_{\tau+n}\in A_n|\mathcal{F}_n)=E_x[1_{A_1\times\dotsm\times A_n}(X_{\tau+1},\dotsc,X_{\tau+n})|\mathcal{F}_{\tau}]$. The reason there is no $x$ on the right-hand side in (1) is because this conditional probability does *not* depend on $x$. It only depends on the value of $X_\tau$.

Comment: Makes sense to me. If you put this last thing as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the main points from the comments to the question in this answer:

For a fixed $x$ you have the probability measure $P_x$ on $\mathcal{X}^\infty$. This is the law of the Markov chain $X$ when it starts from the point $x$. Here you also have a sub-sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. So $P_x(X_{\tau+1}\in A_1,\dotsc,X_{\tau+n}\in A_n|\mathcal{F}_n)=E_x[1_{A_1\times\dotsm\times A_n}(X_{\tau+1},\dotsc,X_{\tau+n})|\mathcal{F}_{\tau}]$. The reason there is no $x$ on the right-hand side in (1) is because this conditional probability does *not* depend on $x$. It only depends on the value of $X_\tau$. This is the essence of the strong Markov property.

Comment: Sir Jakob, are you still there? The notes I've linked above are kind of frustrating; Should I be assuming here that the Markov process is *time-homogeneous*? That is, the transition probabilities $\pi_1, \pi_2,\dots$ are all the same? Does the above lemma still somehow work without the assumption?

Comment: The lemma clearly assumes that the Markov chain is time-homogeneous. To be honest, I've never worked much time-inhomogeneous Markov chains but I'm guessing that if you replace the $\pi$'s in the integrals by something like $\pi_{\tau+1},\dotsc,\pi_{\tau+n}$ then the result is still ok. However, there are some measurability concerns here that you should pay attention to. Since $\tau$ takes values in a countable set I expect that everything is fine though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment/reassurance. I'll just deal with the time homogeneous stuff for now as well. This book really is ass.